# Can't use source control after TFS-to-VSTS transition: "TF30063: You are not authorized to access usga.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection."

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I am using VS2013 and VS2015
I was using TFS for source control for many years
my yahoo email (MS live id account) was used with TFS account

Then I was told that transition has been completed to move from TFS to VSTS and using corporate email (not personal email)

Now, when I login to 
https://mycompany.visualstudio.com/
with new corporate email (selecting 'Work or school account)
I can see my projects.

When 
I open VS 2013 or 2015
log into source control with new corporate email
I am getting "TF30063: You are not authorized to access usga.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection." error
trying to "Get Latest", check-in, manage workspaces, etc...

If I 
log into source control with old personal email
I am getting "TF30063: You are not authorized to access usga.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection." error
trying to "Get Latest", check-in, manage workspaces, etc...

I no longer have access to TFS . . .

I have tried soooo many 'solution' found online. 
Nothing works.

I've tried to un-bind project in VS, but re-bing binds to DefaultCollection again. . .

Please help me to understand what is going on and how do I un-bind from TFS and re-bind to VSTS
Many thanks

Comment: Are others have the same issue? What's the result if you access the source code online `https://XXX.visualstudio.com/[project]/_versionControl`? Try to call `devenv /resetuserdata` command to reset the user data.

Comment: Check the Windows Credential Vault and clear the entries related to the account and to the Windows Live ID.

Comment: What's the result after trying these ways?